# Como montar uma regex?

Tags: regex, coffeescript

Estou montando um bot para o rocketchat para ligar e desligar maquinas no google cloud, preciso montar uma regex que abrange as palavras turnon e turnoff. Alguem poderia me ajudar com isso?

Comment: `/turnon|turnoff/g`?

Comment: @vnbrs `/turn(on|off)/g`?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado `/turno(n|ff)/g`?

Comment: @vnbrs pensei nisso também, mas aí perdia semântica por um ganho questionável de estrutura

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado é quando evitar redundância tende ao exagero

Answer (score 2):

Conforme apontado pelo [@JeffersonQuesado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64969/jefferson-quesado):

```
/turn(on|off)/g
```

A primeira barra indica o início de uma expressão regular. Os parênteses são um [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). O pipe atua como um [operador `ou`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). Por fim, o `/g`, que é a [flag de busca global](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp).

Veja [**funcionando no RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3h96k).

Pode depois pensar em até adicionar o [modificador de case insensitive](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_i.asp), `/i`, se lhe for útil.

E lá no CoffeeScript...

```
pattern = /^turn(on|off)/g;
"turndownforwhat".match(pattern);
> null
"turnon".match(pattern);
> [ 'turnon' ]
```

Veja [**funcionando no repl.it**](https://repl.it/repls/PhonyUnusualAsianlion).